# PDF of $X^n$ where $X$ is normally distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, is there a general way to describe the distribution of $X^n$ for some constant n?

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help at all, but [this](https://www.gstatic.com/education/formulas2/-1/en/normal_distribution.svg) is the general form of a normally distributed random variable's PDF.

Comment: thanks uriyaba! can we get away with directly plugging in $x^n$?

Comment: I highly doubt it, I just posted this general from in case others see this question and might be able to help more than I have. Anyway, what's your familiarity with this subject? Where's the problem coming from? It's important to provide some context when posting questions on this site.

Comment: The context here is that we have a normally distributed r.v. $x$ and are curious about the probability that $x^n$ falls within an interval for some $n>0$. As for familiarity, I have a B.S. degree in math but am working in other science field, so I guess I can say that I know basic stat and probability theory ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding! Now it's more likely that other people may thoroughly help you with this question. If **I** had to guess, the PDF you're looking for would be $$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12(\frac{x^n-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$$ But there might be some more to this question than meets the eye.

Comment: thank you so much uriyaba!

Comment: You're welcome! I'd love for some sort of update when you've finally got the answer for your question, I'm interested :)